# ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Angular 9 role based authentication

Tags: asp.net, angular, identity

I have created a web application with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and angular with the Visual Studio Template and enabled Authentication.
[image]
Then I scaffolded the Identity and added this to the `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => 
options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddIdentityServer().AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

services.AddAuthentication().AddIdentityServerJwt();
```

After that I have created 3 users and assigned them different roles. When I add the Attribute `[Authorize]` to any controller action it works correctly. But how can I make it role based? I have tried `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` But it denied the access. On an unprotected method:

```
 var loggedinUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(userid);
 var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(loggedinUser);
```

the roles list has the Administrator on it, so I do not know what I am missing to make it work. Also inside an Angular component, how can I get the role of the current logged in user?

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to use JWT but I don't know how to connect it to this.authorize.getAccessToken() from angular :/

Answer (score 1):

You can **extend** the implementation of default ProfileService of IdentityServer to include **role** claim like following way.

```
public class ExtendedProfileService : ProfileService<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ExtendedProfileService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser> claimsFactory) : base(userManager, claimsFactory)
    {

    }

    public override async Task GetProfileDataAsync(ProfileDataRequestContext context)
    {
        await base.GetProfileDataAsync(context);
        var user = await UserManager.GetUserAsync(context.Subject);
        var roles = await UserManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        foreach (var role in roles)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("role", role));
        }
        context.IssuedClaims.AddRange(claims);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to register your extended profile service to dependency container

```
services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ExtendedProfileService>();
```